# How to get rid of nested matrices

Tags: matrix, tensors

If I type into Mathematica

```
TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

It gives me a result that has nested matrices. How do I turn that into a normal matrix without any nesting? Thanks

Comment: Look at `Flatten`, `Join`, et al. ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on what dimension your final matrix is supposed to have. When I should make a guess, I would say you want this

```
TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], IdentityMatrix[2]] // ArrayFlatten
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach is to use `KroneckerProduct` which does not require flattening.

From the docs on [TensorProduct](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TensorProduct.html):

> The `KroneckerProduct` of matrices is equivalent to the flattening of their `TensorProduct` to another matrix.

That is, for any two matrices `m1` and `m2`

```
KroneckerProduct[m1, m2] == ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[m1, m2]]
(* True *)
```

So,

```
m1 = IdentityMatrix[2];
KroneckerProduct[m1, m1] == ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[m1, m1]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Excellent. I've been looking to define such a function.  Is there a convenient symbol for it like with the Tensor Product: `esc` `t*` `esc` ?

Comment: @Travis, maybe you can define an input alias such as `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {InputAliases, "KrP"}] = 
 RowBox[{"KroneckerProduct[", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", ",", 
   "\[Placeholder]", "]"}]` and use it as `Esc` `KrP` `Esc` to get a template with placeholders. Or, define `CirclePlus = KroneckerProduct` and us it as `matrix1` `Esc` `c+` `Esc` `matrix2`.